# old theme in 4.0+ app

Tags: android, spinner, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-theme

I've created a spinner in my activity and when i run my app on my Jelly Bean device the theme of the spinner is like 2.x, how can i get the ICS one?

Here's my spinner code :

```
    <Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinnermap"
      style="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

As you can see I tried to set the global style "Holo" but no results..

I had the same problem with a `NumberPicker` but can't remember how I fixed it.

Comment: Have you checked the target in your manifest?

Comment: Yep, my app is for sdk 14 to 17, that's why i wonder why the holo theme was not automatic !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  style="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
```

This is not the solution. **You won't have a fallback on pre HC devices**. 
You need to declare a Theme for your whole application if you want to use the holo theme in your whole app for HC+(I assume this is what you want to have).

In your Manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
</style>
```

values-v11/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>
```

Now you'll have a dropdown spinner on HC+(and also other holo widgets of course)

---

However if you just want to have the spinner to be "holofied" you can do this:

```
<Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinnermap"
      style="@style/MySpinner"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MySpinner" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
</style>
```

values-v11/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MySpinner" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Spinner">
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you mate, I just replace the value style of the spinner by style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner" and it's good, I won't have to create a custom theme juste for one thing.