# My theme changed after using "@style/Theme"

Tags: android, android-activity, themes

I'm using Jelly Bean in my Galaxy S2. If i don't use the Theme property in my activity, it will use the "DefaultDevice" Theme (which i can't currently select from the Manifest don't know why). I wouldn't use the Theme property if i wouldn't need to remove the TitleBar.

Is there any way to use for example Holo? Couldn't understand how to use HoloEverywhere either. I would like to get nice EditText, Buttons and Spinners for my app. Current ones are from Theme.Black which sucks! :( must be like from 2.X android version.

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.traincoders.impl"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="10" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MainActivity" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings_title"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Check this answer out I gave a while back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323117/old-theme-in-4-0-app/14323205#14323205)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
</style>
```

values-v11/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
</style>
```

With this you'll have the Holo Theme on post HC devices and the black theme on pre HC devices.

Comment: Nice Ahmad but i believe there's a problem since i have (Android 2.3.3) in the project library, it says:

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.

Comment: Yeah you have to build it against Honeycomb or above. I recommend building it against the latest SDK version(17)